# delegateEvents hack for decoupling events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I hacked on the Backbone source, but now I am looking for suggestions to make this better.

Here is the source for the method `delegateEvents`:

```
delegateEvents: function (events) {
  if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return;
  this.undelegateEvents();
  for (var key in events) {
    var method = events[key];
    if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
    if (!method) throw new Error('Method "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
    var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
    var eventName = match[1],
      selector = match[2];
    method = _.bind(method, this);
    eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;
    if (selector === '') {
      this.$el.on(eventName, method);
    } else {
      this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
    }
  }
},
```

Here is what I hacked it to (not quite production ready, eh?):

```
delegateEvents: function (events) {
  if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return;
  this.undelegateEvents();
  for (var key in events) {
    var method = events[key];
    var special = false;
    if (method.indexOf('REF->') != -1) {
      special = true;
    } else {
      if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
      if (!method) throw new Error('Method "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
    }
    var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
    var eventName = match[1],
      selector = match[2];
    if (!special) method = _.bind(method, this);
    eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;
    if (selector === '') {
      if (!special) this.$el.on(eventName, method);
    } else {
      if (special) {
        var specialMethod = method.replace('REF->', '');
        eval('this.$el.on(eventName, selector, ' + specialMethod + ');');
      } else {
        this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
      }
    }
  }
},
```

The use-case:

I wanted to remove the logic from the Views, or otherwise just redirect it to a function outside the view. The reason is simple - I'm thinking in terms of pages, not just views, and I'm really using Marionette Layouts to facilitate this; each Layout contains multiple view chunks, and I wanted all the view delegation on the page in one place.

So, if this is standard:

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click li.foo": "fooSelected"
  },
  fooSelected: function (e) {

  }
});
```

The hack works like this:

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click li.foo": "REF->MyApp.Page.fooSelected"
  }
});
```

Is there a better way to decouple this before I go any further?

Comment: Don't Marionette Layouts inherit from Backbone View?  Why can't you register the events on the Layout?  I would think events: `{ "click li.foo" : "fooSelected" }` would work on the layout itself.

Comment: Yes, i know that.. but this is more abstracted. I want to provide a better example, but the best I have is outdated. Regardless, I should be able to easily trigger a pub/sub event, or reference an outside function...without explicitly declaring a function inside the view. I was curious as to how others handled this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the line `if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];` Backbone is already checking if you've given it a function to call rather than a method key on the view object. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4eWn/

Also, with Marionette you could use [View triggers](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtriggers) and then listen for View.on("fooSelected") in your Layout.